# Setting of NSString does'nt work

Tags: uiviewcontroller, nsstring, setter

Hey all,
Here's a funny one. I have two ViewControllers: 
first one (fires on app load) - > displays a textField and a button.
When button is pressed, the text in the textField is to be passed on to the second ViewController through the action method of the button. the second ViewController is to display the text in a Label.
The string remains null :-(
The label does not change :-(

Other thing i did - inside the action method of the first ViewController - I created a new UILabel (you can't see it here...), set its text field to the input i received from the user, then i set the second ViewController's Label to be that one. The label still did not change, but at least the text field of the new label did change. If anyone could explain this to me as well, a=i'll be happy to learn another new thing...

first controller code:

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    UITextField *theTextInput;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *theTextInput;
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;

@end
```

the .m relevant part ("FlipsideViewController" is the secondViewController i mentioned):

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
controller.textToTransmit.text = self.theTextInput.text;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

and this is the second ViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;


@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *textToTransmit;
    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textToTransmit;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
-(void)updateLabel:(NSString *)str;
@end


@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end
```

and it's .m file:

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"


@implementation FlipsideViewController
@synthesize textToTransmit;
@synthesize delegate;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];      
}


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];   
}

....
```

Any of you who had the patience to read through my Q - I will be gratefull for an answer that will help me move forward.

regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reposition your line that sets the text, so that is after your `presentModalViewController`:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

controller.textToTransmit.text = self.theTextInput.text;
[controller release];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to make sure (and for future understanding) - the presentModalViewController actually loads the ViewController, so only after should i take care of iitializations, in a way it's like a viewDidLoad method functionality - speaking?

Comment: the TextField is an UI element and the UI only exist after presenting it (or adding subview). The object in the background (the controller) exist but not the UI. And what I would suggest is to make a NSString attribute to save the text and then set the text to the UI in viedDidLoad or awakeFromNib. (NSString is not UI so you would not have any problems with that) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the line

```
controller.textToTransmit.text = self.theTextInput.text;
```

Check if the UILabel exists (not null), if not maybe you have forgotten to link it up in Interface Builder.

You could also use a NSString-property (instead UILabel) to pass the data to the controller and overwrite the setter-method to set the label's text.